# How to delete a specific row in the table using Swift CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I new to Swift programming. I am using CoreData in my app as a database option.

I am using NSManagedObject (deleteObject) to delete lastObject, firstObject and entire rows in the table.

I want to delete a specific row in the table by using a value which is stored in a variable. I am not using table view (I don't have any index path), this delete operation is the background process after I get response from the my application server.

Any links or tutorials or suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Code for deleting lastObject

```
    if var results1 = context.executeFetchRequest(requestParams, error: nil) as? [Params] {
        println("\n Params Results count : \(results1.count)")
        for param in results1{

            for var n = 0 ;n < results1.count; ++n
            {

            let lastPerson = (results1 as NSArray).lastObject as Params
            context.deleteObject(lastPerson)
            var savingError: NSError?
            context.save(&savingError)


            }

        }
    }
```

Params table consists of columns 'pname' and 'pvalues'.
I want to delete a specific param pname ='server_timeout'.

Consider if 'Params' table consist of 10 rows and 'pname'='server_timeout' might be present at index 5, 6.

How can I find the 'pname' (i.e 'server_timeout') in this list of records and delete it?

Comment: You should show some code, because it's hard to say what you have to do when you don't use a usual TableView

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Using `deleteObject:` removes one object from the persistent store, which is roughly the same as deleting a row in SQL. You're not using SQL, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a predicate that filters out the list to those with `pname` value of `server_timeout` in the first place.

```
context.performBlock {
    requestParams.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pname == %@", "server_timeout")
    if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(requestParams, error: nil) as? [Params] {
        for param in results {
            context.deleteObject(param)
        }
        var error: NSError?
        if !context.save(&error) {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have placed the whole *search-and-delete* inside a `performBlock` closure.  I don't know how you have setup your Core Data, but you might want to consider threading to maximize perceived performance.